# WP_Query Date Query After Minus Hour AND minus minutes

Tags: wp-query

Can't really find information on this and nothing I've tried is working.

Before I had it as,

```
$args = array(
    . . . . . . . .
        'date_query' => array(
            'after'  => '-4 hour',
            'inclusive' => true
        )
);
```

Worked fine. But now I'm trying to make it after `-3 hour` and `-30 minute`..

How do I do this?

```
'date_query' => array(
    'after'    => array(
        'hour'  => '-3',
        'minute' => '-30'
    ),
    'inclusive' => true
```

doesn't work

```
    'date_query' => array(
        // 'after'  => '-4 hour',
        'after'    => array(
            '-4 hour', 
            '-30 minute'
        ),
        'inclusive' => true
    )
```

doesn't work..

I'm sure it's something simple.
Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way translating it to *minutes* only:

```
$args = [ 
    'date_query' => [
        'after'     => '270 minutes ago', // <-- 4 hours and 30 minutes ago
        'inclusive' => true
    ] 
];
```

Comment: This does seem like it's correct, however at least in recent experience, hours and minutes ago seem to always include everything from the days they include. So if you say '24 hours ago' and a post was created 49 hours ago, as long as that 49th hour is still in the same day as the 48th hour, it will be included. So it includes the entire day if any hour of that day is applicable. :/